# Loop through all items in a table mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm going to use this as a cronjob, I'm trying to loop through all of the rows in a table in my database, then update each item in the the row. (I update by calling another website's API to get updated information.) I connect to the database using PDO. My code:

```
$loop = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM item_list");
    $loop->execute();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($loop)){
    ...get new info and update database...
    }
```

I have error checking on and my error is: "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in **page/directory.php** on line 71"

I have all the code written to update each item as it loops through, I just can't get it to loop though.

Comment: Check whether your query executes or not before doing while operation.

Comment: `$loop` is your connection and you want to fetch that? I think it should be somethin like this: `mysql_fetch_array($result)` But without seeing your connection-class I'm not shure what returns you the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing PDO and mysql extension. Use PDO only:

```
while ($row = $loop->fetch()) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$loop = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM item_list");
$loop->execute();

while($row = $loop->fetch()){
...get new info and update database...
}
```

Try this!